# how to generate random number daily (every 24h) and save randomized number that generated day before

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

i need to show random number that change every day (24h) and keep show generated number day before that not change when user refresh page

this what i have only for generate random number

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// this gets an iterable of all elements with a class of "result"
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("result");

// you can use for..of to iterate over the elements. Don't use array methods like forEach on elements, elements is NOT an array.
for( let element of elements )
  element.innerText = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 99999);
    </script>
```

i need the number from script above keep show & not change value for user even when user refresh browser and change every 24h

Comment: This depends on whether you want all users to see the same number daily or each user will get their own number daily. If you want all users to see the same number, you'll need to store it server-side and if you want each user to get their own number, you'll do it client-side and store it with something like `localStorage` and use a time stamp to know if the stored number is out of date or not.

Comment: yes all users see the same number.. how im implement that? localStorage can do that too?

Comment: You'll need to generate, store and update the number via server-side code then. There are a wide variety of languages and architectures for doing this. Stack Overflow isn't a tutorial site on such things.